# Angular: passing message from parent to child is not working

Tags: angular

I tried to pass on a value from parent to child.
But the message only shows up in the parent component, not in the Child.
What's wrong with my code?
Or do I need to import something in `app.module`?

Parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-neues-spiel',
  template: `
      <app-seating-order [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-seating-order>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./neues-spiel.component.scss']
})
export class NeuesSpielComponent implements OnInit {
  parentMessage = "message from parent";
```

Child:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-seating-order',
  template: `
      {{childMessage}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./seating-order.component.scss']
})
export class SeatingOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() childMessage: string;

  constructor() { }
```

Edit:

There is no error in the Console or Webpack.

But if I end ng serve,
the Console shows Errors, but not sure if that's related:

[image]

There is no html, there are component.html files with code, but I commented it out to test it with the Template.

Edit:
App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './core/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppNavbarComponent } from './app-navbar/app-navbar.component';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { NeuesSpielComponent } from './neues-spiel/neues-spiel.component';
import { SeatingOrderComponent } from './seating-order/seating-order.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'neues-spiel', component: NeuesSpielComponent },
  { path: 'seating-order', component: SeatingOrderComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppNavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    NeuesSpielComponent,
    SeatingOrderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AngularFireDatabase],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Does this throw any exceptions/errors? Looks fine to me. Can you add the HTML of the resulting page?

Comment: Is there any error on your browser console?

Comment: @parvanesh check the demo below

Comment: Thanx, did that but it is not working..

Comment: About the Error I get when shutting ng down, see my Post below. Just restarted my computer and started ng again, there was an error "No trace.." but  it went away so fast and did not show up again.

Comment: so, the console displays no errors while running ng serve? Can you please add your app module, and where/how are you rendering the parent component? Is it routed? is it nested in the root component? (app.component). You say that the message only shows in the "parent component", although you dont include the message in the parent´s template...

Comment: That's true, there are no Errors. I also tried it in Firefox (where I don't have any Extensions) and it is also not working. Yes it is routed. I just pasted the App-Module. Yes, it is strange that it showes up in the parent component...

Comment: please add a screenshot of the template in which the message is shown in the parent

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this doesn't work.

However can you make this one change and check if this works? In your child component, instead of having @Input can you try this?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-seating-order',
  inputs: ['childMessage'],
  template: `
   <div>{{childMessage}}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./seating-order.component.scss']
})
export class SeatingOrderComponent implements OnInit { 
  constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the template of the child, place it inside some element. For example:

```
template: `
    <div><h1>{{childMessage}}</h1></div>
`,
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-u6hsn1?file=index.html)**

Comment: Ohh yes, that may be the case. Don't mind, i've edited my answer based on this as well :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no error in the Console or Webpack.

But if I end ng serve,
the Console shows Errors, but not sure if that's related:

[image]

There is no html, there are component.html files with code, but I commented it out to test it with the Template.